# bash changes execution order of command when run from jenkins

Tags: bash, shell

I am using git log to update a release_notes for my project.  When I run the script below on my mac laptop everything works as expected, when I run on jenkins running on centos I see the following as the execution order:

script

```
...
FILE=RELEASE_NOTES
TMP_FILE=${FILE}.tmp
VERSION=$(cat pom.xml | grep "<version>" | head -n1 | sed -e "s/.*\>\(.*\)\<.*/\1/" | tr -d "\-SNAPSHOT")
NAME=$(cat pom.xml | grep "<artifactId>" | head -n1 | sed -e "s/.*\>\(.*\)\<.*/\1/")

echo "$NAME-${VERSION}" > ${TMP_FILE}
git log --pretty="%x09* [%h] %s." $(git describe --abbrev=0)..HEAD >> ${TMP_FILE}

echo "" >> ${TMP_FILE}

if [ -e $FILE ]; then
  cat ${FILE} >> ${TMP_FILE}
fi

mv ${TMP_FILE} $FILE
...
```

jenkins output when run with #!/bin/bash -x

```
+ FILE=RELEASE_NOTES
+ TMP_FILE=RELEASE_NOTES.tmp
++ tr -d '\-SNAPSHOT'
++ head -n1
++ cat pom.xml
++ sed -e 's/.*\>\(.*\)\<.*/\1/'
++ grep '<version>'
+ VERSION='</'
++ head -n1
++ sed -e 's/.*\>\(.*\)\<.*/\1/'
++ cat pom.xml
++ grep '<artifactId>'
+ NAME='</'
+ echo '</-</'
++ git describe --abbrev=0
```

I cant figure out why the execution order is changing.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any inconsistency.  You have several commands running in subshells
(when it sets VERSION and NAME), and those commands have to be executed before
the variable is assigned to, so the /bin/bash -x output above is what I'd expect to see.

If you're talking about the order of the commands within each of those pipelines,
keep in mind that they're all run concurrently, and the exact startup order 
[might not be specified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37513).

Comment: So how do I set it up so that they run in the order i expect so name and version are correct?  Right now they get </ in jenkins but 0.1.52 when run locally.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's probably not the startup order...that shouldn't affect the pipeline output. I'd recommend capturing the intermediate results of each pipeline into their own variables, so you can troubleshoot what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the individual commands in a pipeline are started (which is what `set -x` is showing you) doesn't matter. Data still flows from the left to the right. However, you can set the variables using a single call to `grep` instead of a pipeline. (This does assume GNU `grep`, however).

```
VERSION=$( grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=<version>).*(?=-SNAPSHOT)' pom.xml )
NAME=$( grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=<artifactId>).*(<=</artifactId)' pom.xml )
```

Answer (score 0):

So on mac grep is BSD, linux GNU, so piping seems like it would be the best option to make sure it works on each environment.  But found another solution: maven.

VERSION=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | egrep -v "(^[INFO]|Download)" | tr -d "-SNAPSHOT")
      NAME=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId | egrep -v "(^[INFO]|Download)")

This will let me get the version/name and works on both mac and linux.